# Transfer Function of an Op-Amp Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, transfer-function

This circuit looks like an active high pass filter but without a second series resistor.

[image: Op-Amp Circuit]

1. What is it really?
2. What is the transfer function Vo/Vi?

Comment: What would the TF be if the capacitor were a resistor? Do you know how to derive that?

Comment: Welcome to EE SE! Doesn't the schematic where you found it tell you what it is? Do circuit analysis to find the transfer function. Edit your question to show us your attempt in deriving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [differentiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator). It has a zero at 0 Hz, so it has zero gain at DC, and its gain increases as a function of frequency. As drawn, that circuit will likely become unstable at some high frequency due to real world op-amp limitations.

I used my circuit simulation tool, [Zero](https://git.ligo.org/sean-leavey/zero) (not a coincidence!), to calculate your circuit's transfer function:

[image: Transfer function]

The input file used for Zero is (called with e.g. `zero liso file.txt --save-figure tf.png`):

```
c c1 2u n1 n2
op op1 OP00 gnd n2 n3
r r1 1M n2 n3

freq log 1 1M 1000
uinput n1
uoutput n3
```

Note that this transfer function will look different for a real-world op-amp, which has poles in its feedback. In this case, the phase starts to lag at high frequencies because the op-amp I modelled has a pole somewhere above 1 GHz. In reality, the transfer function will depend on the op-amp you use, but the low frequency response should be similar to that above. If you build this circuit, it would be a good idea to add a capacitor in parallel to the feedback resistor (1Mohm in your case) to help stabilise the feedback.

Comment: Why should this op-amp circuit become unstable at high frequencies and why will adding a capacitor in parallel with the feedback resistor help this?

Comment: Andy aka ...I assume, this is a "polemic" question - and you know the answer?

Comment: @LvW What do you mean by polemic?

Comment: According to [TI's practical differentiator circuit guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa276a/sboa276a.pdf) `A capacitor can be added in parallel with R2 (feedback resistor) to filter the high-frequency noise of the circuit. The capacitor will limit the effectiveness of the differentiator function starting about half a decade (approximately 3.5 times) away from the filter cutoff frequency.` I also couldn't figure it out how it will help stabillize the op amp.

Comment: @Unknown123, perhaps not the correct term (polemic). What I mean is: It was a question with a known answer. Perhaps bettre; A "formal" question?

Comment: The stabilization effect is simple to explain: We have an RC-lowpass with negative phase shift in the feeedback path. This phase shifts adds to the (negative) phase shift of the opamp and can (for high frequencies) if the loop gain is still > 0 dB cause stability problems. A capacitor across the feedback resistor (or another resistor in series to C) can limit (counteract) this negative phase shift - and, thus, inprove the stability margin.